# sql upgrade 2008 -> 2008R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to upgrade my sql from 2008 to 2008R2. I have run the setup, selected upgrade from sql 2000, 2005 or 2008 and followed the install. My managment tools have been upgraded and show version 10.50.1617 but my sql server still shows version 10.0.5500. How do i update my server version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @casperOne why was this closed?  Shouldn't it just be moved to Database Administrators SE? (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Shark It could viably be more a topic for Serverfault as well.

Comment: @casperOne This is a pretty cut and dry DBA task, upgrading instances.

Comment: @Shark I can't migrate this, given the condition it's in: a) your "answer" is a comment (you should know better) and the question and answer have to be updated significantly before I'd migrate over.  We don't want to migrate crap (in the Stack Exchange sense of the word).  Fix up the question, answer, and comments (let me know if you need help with certain ones) and then I'll ship it over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did your upgrade did you select the necessary instance(s) that you in fact did want to upgrade?  Or did you just select management tools?

How do you know your instance is the older version?  Did you do a `select @@version`?

**Edit**:

When you upgraded SQL Server, you selected just the `MSSQLSERVER` instance to upgrade.  This is the default instance, and as you say in your comments you are connecting to a named instance.  What you need to do is during the upgrade process select the appropriate named instance(s) that you want to upgrade.

Comment: When connecting to the server it says the version beside the name. Also, SELECT @@Version is the same value. When running through the installer I selected MSSQLSERVER and when selecting features database engine services is checked (i assumed this would update my server)

Comment: @user1240400 Are you connected to your default instance?  Or a named instance?

Comment: A named instance, ill note that i have my db backed up if blowing away my existing is the easist solution

Comment: @user1240400 That's your problem.  You just upgraded `MSSQLSERVER`, which is your default instance.  You also need to upgrade your named instance(s) if that's what you so desire.

Comment: Despite being close, thank you for the help Shark. Think i got it figured out now.